# Umask not working when using SFTP/SCP directories to achieve 755 for directories, 644 for files

Tags: 20.04, permissions, sftp

I'm using EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 and got the umask set to 022. But however, any file/directory creations are landing up with permissions 775 for directories and 664 for files, just like default 002 umask is considered.

Tried many ways and changed the following:

Added "umask 022" in ~/.bashrc
Added "umask 022" in ~/.profile
Added "umask 022" in /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc
Added "session optional pam_umask.so umask=0022" in /etc/pam.d/login

But none of them worked with FileZilla/WinSCP. I read that none of the above are considered for FTP clients. All I wanted to achieve is to create files and directories with 644 and 755 permissions respectively. Appreciate your help!

Comment: See [SFTP-server uploaded files having wrong rights](https://serverfault.com/q/645150/168875). + So FTP or SFTP, those are two  completely different protocols.

Comment: Thanks! Setting up default permissions in Transfer settings worked fine. I got umask "0022" on server too. But new files are still created with 664 (assuming 002?). Touch works fine as expected - 644. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you *"create new files"*?

Comment: I was using - By right clicking on remote panel, new > file and then create